# how do i make an svg link that scrolls to another part of the svg image

Tags: svg

i.e. like in html clicking a <a href="#x">...</a> tag to scroll to another <a name="x"/> tag (preferable with no or minimal javascript)

When using the a tag this way in svg in chrome no scroll happens